# Using Google Colab to create App on GCP APP ENGINE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, gcloud

I can't install anything on my computer, so I can't install Google Cloud SDK

So I want to play on GCP using a Google Colab

But I fail with the command !gcloud app create

Here is my code and outputs:

```
%pip install google-cloud-language>=2.9.1
PROJECT_ID = "myprojectXXX"  

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user(project_id=PROJECT_ID)
```

✔️ Authenticated

```
!gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com
```

```
!gcloud services enable appengine.googleapis.com
```

```
!gcloud auth list
```

Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE ACCOUNT

- XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com

```
!gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT_ID
```

bindings:
....

- members:
- user:XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
  ...

```
!gcloud app create
```

API [appengine.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [522309567947]. Would you
like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)? (y/N)? y
Enabling service [appengine.googleapis.com] on project [522309567947]...
ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied to enable service [appengine.googleapis.com]
Help Token: ARD_zUb9RQJs5iFgLt81VNfA3FdVaWDebsJQ0vgp6l-iBSS4jhaDyMlBcEpw-T7-0g_mEZ-s1DPTlUGBK5eGLqADr6bkccfqF3t6Yo0TjF37

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
- subject: ?error_code=110002&service=serviceusage.googleapis.com&permission=serviceusage.services.enable&resource=522
  type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  metadata:
  permission: serviceusage.services.enable
  resource: '522309567947'
  service: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  reason: AUTH_PERMISSION_DENIED

Can anyone tip to me understand why permission is denied as I authenticated using my gmail account which has owner role ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you do not have sufficient permissions to enable the App Engine service on your project. Even though you have an owner role, you may need to grant specific permissions to enable App Engine. You may require **App engine admin** and **App Engine Service Admin roles**,apart from these roles check below roles which might help you to resolve the issue:

- **[service account token creator](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#token-creator-role) (it seems you are unable to generate a token)**
- **[App engine service agent role](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/service-agent#service_agent_role) (To your gmail account)**
- **App Engine Creator**
- **App Engine Deployer**

Once you have granted the above roles, try running the command **“gcloud app create”** again. Which may help to resolve the error.

Also refer to the GCP official [**Troubleshoot App Engine errors**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/troubleshooting) for more information.

**EDIT1**:

If you are deploying new versions of an app, you may need to grant **Service Account User role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser)**. Refer to official GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/roles#recommended_role_for_application_deployment) for more details.
After following above suggestions if you are still getting issues,please follow below additional steps

1.Make sure that you are using the **correct project ID** when enabling the App Engine service.

2.Sometimes, restarting the `gcloud` command can resolve permission issues.

**EDIT 2:**

To achieve seamless integration between GCP services and Jupyter Notebook, you need to configure the necessary APIs, permissions, and credentials.

- Try **enabling** the **App Engine Admin API**, if you are not yet enabled.
  Go to the Google Cloud Console >> Click on  **[APIs & Services]** >> Search for and enable the "**App Engine Admin API**".

**Note : Grant the App Engine Admin role to your user account**: A service account acts as an identity for your notebooks and allows them to access GCP resources securely. **Properly add your user account to the app engine admin role.**
Refer :

- [Quick-start tutorial for Google Cloud and Jupyter notebooks](https://mit6874.github.io/tutorials/quickstart/)
- [Step-by-Step Guide for Setting Up a Jupyter Notebook Environment on

  GCP](https://zebrabi.com/guide/how-to-integrate-google-cloud-platform-into-jupyter-notebook/#Step-by-Step_Guide_for_Setting_Up_a_Jupyter_Notebook_Environment_on_GCP)

Comment: thanks a lot for your advices. I tried adding app engine roles to my gmail account without success. I have to explore granting a service account user role. I will try next week. But I didn't find exemples of jupiter notebook connecting to GCP to deploy apps, so I am a bit pessimistic. Thx a lot, I will continue searching next week

Comment: Thanks for your response, based on your comment, I updated my response in the answer EDIT2 section, please have a look.

Comment: unfortunately even after granting "App Engine Admin API" role to my user account (witch is also owner) it doesn't change the error message when I pass "!gcloud app create". The link "Step-by-Step Guide for Setting Up a Jupyter Notebook Environment on GCP" explain how to run a jupyter notebook on GCP, not how a jupyter notebook running on Google Colab can manage a project. But nevermind, I will find other way of working it through. Thx a lot

Comment: if anyone wants to try it by himself : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GiKe7eB8zVcWIt4E0SdPFU_NgkXGMOF8?usp=sharing